# Is the Geth at the end of Priority: Geth Dreadnought from any of the previous games?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I just finished Priority: Geth Dreadnought and there was a Geth named Geth VI who was sending out the Reaper signal. Was this Geth significant in any of the other games? The way the camera work is done, it looks as if this is supposed to be a significant character.

To me, it just looks like all the other Geth I was just shooting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If Legion survived in Mass Effect 2, the Geth that is used to transmit the Reaper signal will be him. If you get a generic Geth you probably started from a save where Legion didn't survive the suicide mission or where you never activated him.

So this Geth is intended to be an important character, but only if Legion, the geth that joined you in Mass Effect 2 survived. In your case you got the generic replacement geth.